# How to make a 3d css capsule

Tags: css, sass

Can anyone help me make a 3d drug capsule in scss or css. I need it as a loading icon. Like the one [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+drug+capsule&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=AZUihv2LTi-RtM%253A%252CWtFZRnAiDqZ8EM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kSQQ0pVj1M01EpLleUkU0j0UTeI-w&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIgJaTkqTkAhViTxUIHaiZAgUQ9QEwAXoECAkQCQ#imgrc=AZUihv2LTi-RtM:)

Comment: Thank you so much @frederick99....Its perfect, i couldn't thank you enough.....heyyyy but how come I have a minus 1, what did I do wrong now?

Comment: You can post the code and I will mark it as the answer

Comment: You may have received downvotes because your question was very board and you also haven't posted any code or told us anything you have tried in the past. hopes this help with posting questions in the future :)

Comment: Thanks but if people read the question well. It implies that I havent tried anything in the past because it is a "How to" question

Comment: *I havent tried anything in the past because it is a "How to" question* --> those question are off-topic and you will most likely get downvotes and close votes.

Comment: @NSJCorps Stackoverflow is very harsh towards newcomers, and it's the reason many of them turn to alternate platforms like Reddit where the communities are much more welcoming. I am not saying they are wrong in doing to; just stating. Also, the question will probably get closed (I'm surprised it's still up) so there is nothing in it for me in posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample using a single `div` element. Feel free to change any elements (colors, shadows, animations?, etc.) that you want.

```css
#capsule {
  width:120px;
  height:50px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow:
    -1px 13px 17px -10px #000000d9,
    -8px -9px 17px 9px #000000ab inset;
}
#capsule:after, #capsule:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: .8;
}
#capsule:after{
  background: #009ff3;
}
#capsule:before{
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="capsule"></div>
```

Comment: Here's the link to the original pen: https://codepen.io/frederick99_/pen/pozPVmx/left?editors=0100